# VR hand Control is not working while loading the Next scene in Unity Vrtk

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrtk

In My app initial page is login after Login app will navigate to Scene 1 (Here control is working fine).

After Completing the Scene 1 app navigates to Scene 2.

Here is my problem, VR Hand controller is not working in this scene.(**But works after Restarting the VR hand controller**)

How to solve this either via script or by something else??

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. Just Uncheck the **persist onload** in obsolete settings under VRTK SDK Manager